# WPF 4.5 Microsoft's Ribbon: which control of RibbonApplicationMenu

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribbon-control, wpf-4.5

I am using Microsoft's `Ribbon` of WPF 4.5 and developing application using VS2012 (C#) on Win 8 machine. I want to make my application show `RibbonApplicationMenu` like the "File"-menu of Office Word 2010, but I can't find out which control is used for it (see attached screenshot, red-marked control number 1 and 2). I also tried `RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem` but it is more like Office old-style.
Maybe anyone can tell me. Thank you in advance.

[image: Which control is used]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer in wpf sample browser of infragistics netadvantage. The no. 1 is called "backstage" (ribbon 2010 style), no. 2 is a "application menu item".
(in my opinion) The infragistics' ribbon is easier to use than the Microsoft's one, since I can't find tutorial how to create backstage (ribbon 2010 style); the existing tutorials are mostly using old ribbon (2007 style). 
Here take a look my simple code snippet:

```
<Window x:Class="TestRibbon.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"
    xmlns:igRibbon="http://infragistics.com/Ribbon"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="768"
    Width="1024"
    Title="Test Ribbon"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
        <igRibbon:XamRibbon x:Name="ribbonMain" 
                            Width="Auto" 
                            ApplicationMenuMode="Office2010" 
                            ApplicationAccentColor="Blue">
            <igRibbon:XamRibbon.ApplicationMenu2010>
                <igRibbon:ApplicationMenu2010 Caption="File">
                    <igRibbon:ApplicationMenu2010Item KeyTip="I"
                        Header="Information">
                        <igRibbon:ApplicationMenu2010Item.Content>
                            <Grid Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="Black" Text="IP" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,20,0,0" />
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGray" Text="192.168.2.1" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </igRibbon:ApplicationMenu2010Item.Content>
                </igRibbon:ApplicationMenu2010>
            </igRibbon:XamRibbon.ApplicationMenu2010>
        </igRibbon:XamRibbon>
    </Grid>
</window>
```

Answer (score 4):

1) I suggest you use the ribbon that's inside .net 4.5 (add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon). I'm not sure what you used the external one.
2)What you need for a menu is Ribbon.ApplicationMenu

3) Below is a working ribbon (based on that) that includes several types of buttons as well as a menu that you require.
All you need for this to work is to add an images folder with an "options.png" in it.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Ribbon  SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">

            <!-- Help Pane, located at the right-hand side -->
            <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" />
            </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>

            <!-- Quick Access Toolbar - located at the upper-left corner -->
            <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
                    <RibbonButton x:Name ="Save" SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" />
                    <RibbonSplitButton x:Name ="Undo" SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" >
                        <RibbonSplitMenuItem Header="Undo 1" />
                        <RibbonSplitMenuItem Header="Undo 2" />
                    </RibbonSplitButton>
                    <RibbonSplitButton x:Name="Redo" SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" >
                        <RibbonSplitMenuItem Header="Redo 1" />
                        <RibbonSplitMenuItem Header="Redo 2" />
                    </RibbonSplitButton>
                    <RibbonCheckBox Label="Sound" KeyTip="X" />
                </RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
            </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <!-- Application Menu, located at the left-hand side (down arrow) -->
            <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <RibbonApplicationMenu KeyTip="F">
                    <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Options1" ImageSource="Images\options.png" />
                    <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Exit2" ImageSource="Images\options.png" />
                </RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

            <!-- Ribbon Tab #1: Home -->
            <RibbonTab Header="Home" KeyTip="H" >

                <!-- Home  group-->
                <RibbonGroup x:Name="ClipboardGroup" Header="Home">
                    <RibbonMenuButton LargeImageSource="Images\options.png" Label="Activate" KeyTip="V">
                        <RibbonToggleButton SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" Label="blabla" KeyTip="H" />
                        <RibbonToggleButton SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" Label="option2" />
                    </RibbonMenuButton>
                    <RibbonToggleButton SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" Label="Toggle " KeyTip="X" />
                    <RibbonToggleButton x:Name="Toggle11" SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" Label="Just a Toggle" KeyTip="FP" />

                </RibbonGroup>

                <!-- Employee And Payroll group-->
                <RibbonGroup x:Name="Employee" Header="Adjust View">
                    <RibbonMenuButton LargeImageSource="Images\options.png" Label="Test" KeyTip="V">
                        <RibbonMenuItem ImageSource="Images\options.png" Header="Keep Text Only" KeyTip="T"/>
                        <RibbonMenuItem ImageSource="Images\options.png" Header="Paste Special..." KeyTip="S"/>
                    </RibbonMenuButton>
                    <RibbonCheckBox SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" Label="Sound" KeyTip="X" />

                </RibbonGroup>


            </RibbonTab>

            <!-- Ribbon Tab #2: Launch -->
            <RibbonTab Header="Settings" KeyTip="I">
                <!-- Launch/Applications group-->
                <RibbonGroup Header="Settings">
                    <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\options.png" Label="Record" KeyTip="C" />
                </RibbonGroup>

            </RibbonTab>
            <RibbonTab Header="PageLayout" KeyTip="L">
                <!-- Launch/Applications group-->
            </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I couldn't get the labels shown in the RibbonButton of RibbonQuickAccessToolBar until I wrapped the "RibbonButton"s with a DockPanel.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu>
                <RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                    <Label Content="Right panel!"></Label>
                </RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Exit" Click="ShutDown" />
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

haha